# How do i redirect with GoDaddy domain

Tags: redirect, godaddy-api

hey I am trying to redirect users to a site if they go to jshstudios.com/app-ads.txt
if they go to jshstudios.com/app-ads.txt I want to redirect them to https://jacobscheelhansen.wixsite.com/jshstudios/_functions/appadstxt how do I do this in GoDaddy